# Is thermal dissipation of resistors a thermodynamic necessity of the Ohm I-V relationship?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrical-resistance

We know that all resistors dissipate at a rate $I^2 R = V^2 /R$.

But I'm wondering if it is possible to prove that a component with a linear relationship between current and voltage ($ I \propto V$) must dissipate at a rate $\propto I^2$ on entirely thermodynamic arguments.

Comment: Why 'thermodynamic arguments'? Lost energy in the element per unit time is $VI$ based solely on the definition of potential difference $V$, which is introduced in electromagnetic theory. For linear element, this already implies dissipation at rate $\propto I^2$. No thermodynamic arguments are needed.

Comment: thermodynamic arguments since we only know that the resistor is giving up energy at that rate, but without a thermodynamic argument, we could in principle speculate the existence of an Ohmic component that stores useful energy at a rate $IV$ somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Onsager relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-equilibrium_thermodynamics#The_Onsager_relations) in thermodynamics state that the rate of entropy production (which can be related to the power dissipated at constant temperature) is proportional to the product of the flow (here, the current flux $I/A$ for a cross-sectional area of $A$) and the field (here, the electric field $V/L$ for a conductor length of $L$).

Since you've stated that Ohm's Law holds (i.e., $V\propto I$), then the electric field $V/L$ must scale with the current flux $I/A$ (and the resistivity). Assuming that the dimensions stay constant, the heat dissipated is thus proportional to $I^2$.

Comment: Something I'm not sure is if this does address very general cases where $$\Delta V \propto \Delta I$$, but globally $$V(I)$$ is a complicated dependency. Transistors, for example.