# Does $V=IR$ apply to a non-ohmic conductor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

What happens to the potential difference for example in a thermistor when the current is increased? The main question is does $V=IR$ apply to a non-ohmic conductor?

Comment: For a DC circuit, resistance is defined as V/I.  Resistance values may change with temperature and other conditions, but that doesn't change the definition.

Comment: See this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357945/955

Comment: @HotLicks, an alternative (and in many cases, better) definition is $R = \frac{{\rm d}V}{{\rm d}I}$, which is making a small signal approximation in which the device or load is locally Ohmic, even if it isn't Ohmic over a wide range of conditions. IMO, defining $R=V/I$ is more confusing than helpful for students who want to study beyond the electrician or technician's level of detail, which is hopefully most people using this site.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, non-Ohmic conductors are those who don't follow Ohm's law.
Examples are diodes, transistors and *etc.*

As for your thermistor, it is actually an Ohmic conductor since it satisfies

$$V=IR$$

just with a temperature dependent $R=R\left(T\right)$. Keep in mind that every device's parameters are temperature dependent. In a thermistor, however, this dependency is greater than in standard devices.

Comment: Please could you explain what you meant by "your thermistor, it is actually an ohmic conductor since it satisfies V=IR" I did not understand this statement as I thought a thermistor is a non-ohmic conductor, as the voltage is not proportional to current.

Comment: @saraahmed The voltage **is** proportional to the current. However, the proportionality constant may differ for different temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

The relation $$V=IR$$ also holds for a non-ohmic conductor (resistor). The only difference to an ohmic conductor is that the resistance $R$ is not constant but can depend on current $I$, voltage $V$, or even on time.